# Calling stored procedure using c# by passing parameter that is declared inside the repository method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ado.net-entity-data-model

Here am Passing employeename as parameter but declared inside the method instead of at the method call and then added as a parameter to the stored procedure. But the result i get here includes all the employeename data. What am I trying to achieve here is to get data for John from GetEmployee method, instead am getting data for all employeenames in the view. Any ideas where am doing wrong?

```
public IList<EmployeeModel> GetEmployee()
    {         
        string employeeName= "John";
            List<EmployeeModel> empdata;
            using (DbCommand cmd = this.UoW.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "getemployee";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.AddParameter("employeeName", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, employeeName);
                cmd.AddParameter("outputcur", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output, string.Empty);
                empdata= cmd.ExecuteQuery<EmployeeModel>();
            }
            return empdata;              
    }

}
```

Here's the code in procedure

```
PROCEDURE getemployee(employeeName VARCHAR, outputcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) IS
   BEGIN
    OPEN outputcur FOR SELECT
                          *
                     FROM
                         V_EMPLOYEE
                     WHERE
                         empname= employeeName; //John is the employeename

END;
```

And here in this method which is different from above, am passing parameter while calling it,and  it works

```
public IList<AllEmployeeModel> GetAllEmployees(string employeeId)
    {

            List<AllEmployeeModel> allempdata= new List<AllEmployeeModel>();

            using (DbCommand cmd = this.UoW.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "getallemployees";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.AddParameter("employeeId", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input,employeeId);

             cmd.AddParameter("output",Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor,ParameterDirection.Output, string.Empty);

                allempdata= cmd.ExecuteQuery<AllEmployeeModel>();
            }
            return allempdata;

    }
```

Comment: Those are different stored procedures.  It does not matter if the parameter is being passed in or declared inside the method.  The result you are getting is what is coming back from the stored procedure.  I suggest you execute the stored procedures directly in the database to see what is being returned.  Also monitor the queries to actually se query being used to call the stored procedures.

Comment: Awesome.... thankyou for the suggestion, I looked it into the query as you said and it is returning all data and this happened because the parameter that i passed and column that i used in where clause is same so Oracle took it silmilar to 'Where 1=1'  case and it worked!. Thanks again :) @JonathanAlfaro